# Alien registration card in China

Tags: indian-citizens, china, internship, bureaucracy

I am Indian student planning to visit China for internship purpose. I was applying for Visa through a Visa agent in Chinese embassy in Delhi. I was just told by the agent that the embassy is demanding "Alien registration card". I don't exactly know what it means. For all the previous students who did internship in China from India this was not required. Can anyone shed some light on the query?

I am an Indian residing in India.

Comment: Are you residing in India at the moment?  Or are you elsewhere applying via an agency?

Comment: I am an Indian citizen residing in India.

Comment: Why are you using a visa agent?  You should apply directly if possible, or find an agent who knows what he's doing.  This one seems not to.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand it,

- If you are a non-Indian national residing in India and
- You apply for a Chinese visa **in India** (not in your home country)

You need an "[alien registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_registration) card" - presumably a kind of identity card issued by India to non-Indian nationals residing in India.

Comment: The corollary to this is that Shubham Ugare should consider using a different agent; this one seems not to know what he is doing.